# Why my page show horizontal scrollbar on small screen?

Tags: css, responsive-design, scrollbar

I have responsive HTML [page](http://jcubic.pl/test/) and it show scrollbar when width is smaller then 691px, how to hide that scrollbar? What make that scrollbar to show up?

Comment: On FF, I trigger the horizontal scrolling at a width of about 431px, are we looking at the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a subtle CSS effect because of how you styled your `footer` element.

In your footer (which is absolutely positioned), you have two child elements, `nav` and `#copy`, both of which use absolute positioning.

Without going into the details of how the widths of absolutely positioned elements are computed, the scroll bar is due primary because of how you positioned the copyright notice.

In one rule, `footer #copy` you set `left: 50%` and in the child div `footer #copy p` you set `position: relative, left: -50%`.

Shifting things to the left by 50% and then back to the right by 50% does not quite cancel out and as a result, one of these elements has a width that computes to a value that causes the overflow condition, hence the scroll bar.

There is no real good way of fixing this because the CSS is overly complicated for what you are trying to do.

I would start by not using so much absolute positioning, not really needed in this case.

You can hide the scroll bar by removing `white-space: nowrap` (line 174 and 215 in style sheet) but then this breaks your layout even more.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I was able to fix it using `overflow: hidden` on the footer and change few things.

Comment: The problem was identifying the trouble spot, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS you have

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
    footer nav {
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
    }  
}
```

left:50%; is the guilty party

Comment: If this is the problem, why scrollbar is not show up on 800px?

Comment: Because there's enough space for this to work until the viewport hits about 690px. Similar issue with footer #copy {left: 50%;bottom: -10px;}

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa What browser are you working with? I see the effect around a screen width of 431px.

Comment: @MarcAudet - Using Mac Safari I can see that the footer nav extends past the right of the viewport starting around 690 px. With FF I see the same thing though the horizontal scroll bar (in FF) doesn't show up until around 430px, as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

This is the cause:

> `footer {    white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: Removing `white-space: nowrap` hides the scroll bar but causes even more of a mess with the layout.  The footer uses too much absolute positioning and the computed widths are really the issue here.